# TypeError: simple_query() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, tkinter

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

class mySQL:
    def __init__(self):
        #MySQL Credentials
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="XXXX-XX99",
        user="root",
        passwd="TEST",
        database="technical")
        #Cursor
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def simple_query(self,sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.state('zoomed')
        self.master.geometry('400x700')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        #Entries and text-box
        self.nameLabel = Label(self.frame, text = "Name of Person Making Request:")
        self.nameEntry = Entry(self.frame)
        # Buttons
        self.btn = Button(self.frame, text = "Submit", command = self.sendData)
        # Organizing above^
        self.nameLabel.pack()
        self.nameEntry.pack()
        self.btn.pack()

    def sendData(self):
        x = mySQL()

        #Values
        values = (
        self.nameEntry.get(),
        )

        #Insert Command
        x.simple_query("INSERT INTO document_control (person) values ('%s')", values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Goal:**

Inside my class `mySQL` and function `simple_query(self,sql)` is used in my class `MainWindow` at function `sendData(self)`. (see `x.query("INSERT..."`) I am trying to make this work, simply insert values into MySQL.

When I press the button `submit`- (activates function `sendData(self)`) error comes up with:

```
TypeError: simple_query() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I am not quite sure why the output is TypeError.

Where Im I going wrong here? Which section of the code do I need to change? And what needs changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def simple_query(self, sql):
     self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

and

```
x.simple_query("INSERT INTO document_control (person) values ('%s')", values)
```

Here you are passing 2 arguments to `simple_query` (the query string and `values`) but it only accepts one, `sql` (`self` is the instance, in this case `x`, and is passed implicitly).

Other answers make your code work, but they also make it vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

For example, if someone were to enter the string `a'); delete from document_control; --` in the GUI then the executed query will be

```
INSERT INTO document_control (person) values ('a'); delete from document_control; -- ')
```

Not so good...

Instead of using string interpolation you should use a parameterized query. It can be done by allowing `simple_query` to accept an optional `arguments` tuple.

```
def simple_query(self, sql, args=None):
    if not args:
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
    else:
        self.cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Keep in mind that `args` should be a tuple or a list.

Comment: That made me more aware of SQL injection - thanks for that!

Comment: Just realized I had to add in `self.db.commit()` at end of each cursor too

Comment: used the sql injection above - what does this mean? --- `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Use multi=True when executing multiple statements`

Answer (score 1):

use the command

```
x.simple_query("INSERT INTO document_control (person) values ('%s')" %values)
```

I tested like

```
class Test():

    def simple_query(self, message):
        print(message)


x = Test()
values = 'asasda'
x.simple_query("INSERT INTO document_control (person) values ('%s')" %values)
```

Comment: So simply replaced the `,` with a `%`? What's the difference?

Comment: This makes the code vulnerable to SQL injection (`values` comes directly from user input). Use a parameterized query instead

Comment: With `%` you're formatting the string. With `,` you're passing multiple parameters.

Comment: @DeepSpace can you give me an example how it can be injected via tkinter?

Comment: @LV98, yes simply replace , with %